# How to exactly execute onload script & exit pop up?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Display message when user leaves site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753827/display-message-when-user-leaves-site)

Ok, this is my situation - I'd like my user to start a download automatically when they land on my page, which I had this code:

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('download').click()">
<a id="download" href="http://www.website.com/file.zip" style="display:none;">Download</a>
```

This works.

However the problem is that, I have another script at the bottom that executes a popup message when the user tries to leave the page as follows:

```
<script language="javascript">
var exitsplashalertmessage = '***************************************\n\n         > > > W A I T < < <\n\n     CLICK THE ***CANCEL*** BUTTON\n    on the NEXT Window for Something\n             VERY Special!\n\n***************************************';
var exitsplashmessage = '***************************************\n\n W A I T   B E F O R E   Y O U   G O !\n\n  CLICK THE *CANCEL* BUTTON RIGHT NOW\n     TO STAY ON THE CURRENT PAGE.\n\n I HAVE SOMETHING VERY SPECIAL FOR YOU!\n\n***************************************';
var exitsplashpage = 'http://www.website.com/more';
</script>
<script language="javascript" src="http://www.website.com/exitsplash.php"></script>
```

And the problem now is that, the download file works fine, but the exitsplash doesn't execute.

I have been told that I need to "onUnload" the code in the  ... but how can I do this?

Anyone, any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: y u write spammy websites?! :(

Answer (score 0):

You should use onbeforeunload. You can do it either in HTML or Javascript.

HTML:

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('download').click();" onbeforeunload="alert('your message'); return false;">
```

Javascript:

```
document.body.onbeforeunload = function(){
    var exitSplashMessage = "your message";
    alert(exitSplashMessage);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: So what exactly does onbeforeunload do?
I don't want a popup message when the download finishes.
What I actually want is the message in the exitsplash message as shown...

Comment: onbeforeunload asks the user to either stay or leave the page when he tries to close the window or leave the actual page. It won't fire when the download finishies since it's on the load event. Try it and you will see.